# Ошибка при работе с OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

Пользуюсь этой [инструкцией](https://robotclass.ru/tutorials/opencv-python-find-contours/), чтобы изучить библиотеку OpenCV

Столкнулся с такой проблемой (я помимо этого этого сайта, так же смотрел другие, и во всех почти одна и та же ошибка):

Вот код:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

# параметры цветового фильтра
hsv_min = np.array((2, 28, 65), np.uint8)
hsv_max = np.array((26, 238, 255), np.uint8)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(__doc__)

    fn = "C:\\Users\\NAMEUSER\\Desktop\\231.jpg" # путь к файлу с картинкой
    img = cv.imread(fn)

    hsv = cv.cvtColor( img, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV ) # меняем цветовую модель с BGR на HSV
    thresh = cv.inRange( hsv, hsv_min, hsv_max ) # применяем цветовой фильтр
    # ищем контуры и складируем их в переменную contours
    _, contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours( thresh.copy(), cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    # отображаем контуры поверх изображения
    cv.drawContours( img, contours, -1, (255,0,0), 3, cv.LINE_AA, hierarchy, 
    cv.imshow('contours', img) # выводим итоговое изображение в окно cv.waitKey()
    cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Вот ошибка:

```
line 18, in <module>
_, contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours( thresh.copy(), cv.RETR_TREE, 
cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) ValueError: not enough values to
unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

Как решить данную проблему? картинка должна быть нужного размера и нужного формата...

18-ая строчка:

```
_, contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours( thresh.copy(), cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)**"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Туториал описывает, наверное, какую-то старую версию OpenCV, в которой функция `FindContours` возвращала три параметра. В OpenСV 3 и 4 возвращается кортеж из двух значений, да и в 2.4, я смотрю, [тоже](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours)

Поэтому просто удалите `_`

Comment: Спасибо, всё верно, проблема была в версионости библиотеки